# MediaTrack detect highest level

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I have several audio tracks, which i got from getUserMedia (microphone). Those are being transmitted via WebRTC.
I want to highlight the stream that is active at the moment, but checking the documentation for [MediaTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack) i cannot find any method to access something that allows me to determine if that object is the most active at the moment.

So, if there is a method to get the current output, with some filter i should be able to determine which one is the "most active" one and highlight it.

Does such method exist in the API? Is there another approach that i can take for that?

Answer (score 2):

`MediaStream` Object has APIs [refer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_media_stream_apis.htm) to detect active stream but not its `MediaStreamTrack`.

Even if you want to detect active speaker via volume level you need to pass `MediaStream` to Web audio API - AudioContext to analyse it. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318361/analyze-sound-stream-without-duplicating-it/42319419?noredirect=1#comment71792089_42319419)

If you have proper RTCPeerConnection then you can use getStats API. [example](http://blog.telenor.io/webrtc/2015/06/11/getstats-chrome-vs-firefox.html)

Answer (score 1):

MediaStreamTrack doesn't have such a property. You can use the webaudio api as done by [hark](https://github.com/otalk/hark) to get a volume indication and then determine who is speaking.

Your mileage may vary though, active speaker detection is a hard problem.